# How to get Product Id from Item Object in Observer?

Tags: event-observer

**Controller File:**

```
public function editAction()
{                                                                                                                                                         
   $quoteId=$this->getRequest()->getParam("quoteid");
   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
   Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', $quote);
}
```

**Observer File:**

```
public function changePrice($observer) {
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
echo "<pre>";print_r($item->getProductId());
exit();
```

How to get Product Id in Observer from Item?

If you have any idea then share here please.

Thank You.

Comment: Please confirm the magento version

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Thank for the reply. 
Magento Ver: 1.9.3.3

Comment: try like this $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();

Comment: We get Item Object with `$item = $observer->getEvent();` but product Id not exist in it.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa any idea you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following according to your requirement

```
$items = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

or

```
$items = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Both will provide you with the array

```
foreach($items as item){
    $item->getData(); //this will give you all the necessary information about the item
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Not Working for me.

Comment: We get Item Object with `$item = $observer->getEvent();` but product Id not exist in it.

Comment: If I am not wrong then, $observer->getEvent(); will give you the event object and not the item object. Check again by using xdebug or var_dump the object.

Comment: Yes,  you are right.

Comment: any idea you have?